# Kinda Piracy, Kinda Not

Tags: halal-haram, game, piracy

I have a question. So I was wondering if something is considered haram or not. So I play this game called “The Walking Dead”. In this game there are 4 seasons. Now I have a question.
Let’s say I pay for season 1. Could I pirate season 2 of the game? Because I am not completely just taking something with no pay. But I’m basically just under paying. Is it still haram if I only pay for 1 season and pirate the other 3?

Comment: It is possible that the game was made by two different development teams or even a different director. Your first season was given to Team A, but when you pirate Season 2, the money isn't going to Team B at all.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the best one could say about playing games in Islam is that it is makruh as it disturbs you from worshiping Allah and is a waste of time. Secondly paying for a game might also be regarded as a waste of wealth which you'd be asked for in the hereafter.

And further if this game has a copy right I'd doubt that any scholar would consider pirating it as permissible. As Allah said:

> O you who have believed, fulfill [all] contracts. Lawful for you are the animals of grazing livestock except for that which is recited to you [in this Qur'an] - hunting not being permitted while you are in the state of ihram. Indeed, Allah ordains what He intends. ([5:1](https://legacy.quran.com/5/1))

And terms of uses, licenses and copy rights are a kind of contract.